# ObservableCollection<Double[]> and XAML

Tags: multidimensional-array, observablecollection

I have a class that inherits ObservableCollection< Double[] > (let's call it "TestClass"). I.e. collection of double arrays. Can I use this kind of collection in XAML. I'm trying to add items but it looks like I cannot add double arrays as items. Is this even possible?

Something like this:

```
<TestClass>
  <x:Array Type="sys:Double">
    <!-- What comes here...? -->
  </x:Array>
</TestClass>
```

Actually, I would rather like to use ObservableCollection< Double[,] > but I think it's impossible - two-dimensional array I mean.

Help me out here... :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a ViewModel. The ViewModel will be your container class where we insert custom double-arrays or fetch them from the database. If it's not just a lookup, you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (but that's a different topic):

```
namespace MyCompany.Common.ViewModels
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public class PointsArrayVM
    {
        private double[] _points;
        public double[] Points
        {
            get
            {
                return _points;
            }
            set
            {
                _points = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I'll add two custom records of double[] (firstArray & secondArray). I then assign the collection to a CollectionViewSource, and (just to illustrate) I assign more records from the database to a second CollectionViewSource with the exposed MainViewModel property, **List<PointsArrayVM> DatabasePoints**. If it's not just a lookup, you will need an ObservableCollection instead of a List. In your XAML, under Window.Resources, add the following:

```
    <x:Array x:Key="firstArray" Type="sys:Double"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <sys:Double>1.1</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double>1.2</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double>1.3</sys:Double>
    </x:Array>

    <x:Array x:Key="secondArray" Type="sys:Double"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <sys:Double>2.1</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double>2.2</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double>2.3</sys:Double>
    </x:Array>

    <x:Array x:Key="pointsArray" Type="{x:Type viewmodels:PointsArrayVM}"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Common.ViewModels;assembly=Common">
        <viewmodels:PointsArrayVM Points="{StaticResource firstArray}"/>
        <viewmodels:PointsArrayVM Points="{StaticResource secondArray}"/>
    </x:Array>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="customPointsCollectionViewSource" Source="{StaticResource pointsArray}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="databasePointsCollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding DatabasePoints}"/>
```

Now that we have our CollectionViewSources, we can add them to a CompositeCollection with CollectionContainers. In this example I'm using Points[0] as the display text, and Points[1](http://soumya.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/wpf-simplified-part-11-xaml-tricks/) as the selected value:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding PointsFilter}" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          SelectedValuePath="Points[0]" DisplayMemberPath="Points[1]">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource customPointsCollectionViewSource}}"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource databasePointsCollectionViewSource}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

I hope this helps! For some very informative XAML tips, have a look at [**this**](http://soumya.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/wpf-simplified-part-11-xaml-tricks/) site.

---

**Regarding your second question**

Yes, WPF seems to have a problem with assigning a control path to a specific point in a multi-dim array. You can however work around this by also having a Points2DArray ViewModel that contains an array of PointsArrayVM objects:

```
namespace MyCompany.Common.ViewModels
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public class Points2DArrayVM
    {
        private PointsArrayVM[] _pointsArrays;
        public PointsArrayVM[] PointsArrays
        {
            get
            {

                return _pointsArrays;
            }
            set
            {
                _pointsArrays = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in your XAML, you can now put the collections of one ViewModel into the other container ViewModel:

```
<x:Array x:Key="pointsArray1" Type="{x:Type viewmodels:PointsArrayVM}"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Common.ViewModels;assembly=Common">
    <viewmodels:PointsArrayVM Points="{StaticResource firstArray}"/>
    <viewmodels:PointsArrayVM Points="{StaticResource secondArray}"/>
</x:Array>

<x:Array x:Key="pointsArray2" Type="{x:Type viewmodels:PointsArrayVM}"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Common.ViewModels;assembly=Common">
    <viewmodels:PointsArrayVM Points="{StaticResource firstArray}"/>
    <viewmodels:PointsArrayVM Points="{StaticResource secondArray}"/>
</x:Array>

<x:Array x:Key="points2DArray" Type="{x:Type viewmodels:Points2DArrayVM}"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Common.ViewModels;assembly=Common">
    <viewmodels:Points2DArrayVM PointsArrays="{StaticResource pointsArray1}"/>
    <viewmodels:Points2DArrayVM PointsArrays="{StaticResource pointsArray2}"/>
</x:Array>

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="customPointsCollectionViewSource" Source="{StaticResource points2DArray}"/>
```

Then in your ComboBox, it would be something like:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding PointsFilter}" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          SelectedValuePath="PointsArrays[0].Points[0]" DisplayMemberPath="PointsArrays[0].Points[1]">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource customPointsCollectionViewSource}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```